# How to remove acceleration time of WindowsMouse Keys?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, mouse-keys

As I disconnect my mouse sometimes to gain some space for other devices, I'm still using Mouse Keys. However, the acceleration time takes away my patience.

I've once used a Windows Ghost Image, in which the Mouse keys has no acceleration time, so I know that it may be possible to remove it. I've edit the `timetomaximumspeed` in the Registry but it just makes the Mouse keys slower. I've searched online.

The only similar question which was posted on Microsoft forum have got no answer. I've tried alternatives like Neat Mouse but the experience is not as good because the keymap isn't the same. I'm currently using Windows 7.

I'm willing to edit everything, even a DLL file maybe?

Comment: In *Control Panel > Mouse > Pointer Options*, is "Enhance pointer precision" unchecked?

Comment: I've tried unchecking it, the mouse keys still hasn't gained any speed.

Comment: Try in *Control Panel > Ease of Access > Ease of Access Centre > Make the keyboard easier to use > Set up Mouse Keys*, to set under Pointer speed the Acceleration to the lowest setting.

Comment: Yes I have set that to fastest setting. Yet the acceleration time is still at about 1 second. I want to reduce it to 0, as I have tried a ghost mod some years ago which have one. Control Panel Settings is not a choice. Maybe a deeper intervention might help.

Comment: You said "set that to fastest setting", shouldn't you set it to the lowest if you are trying to disable acceleration?

Comment: Thank you. I've made an AutoHotkey script myself to replace Mousekeys. If you want to have a look, may you [go here](https://github.com/uahnbu/mousekeys/blob/master/mouse.ahk)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not much that you can do with Windows mouse keys. Removing pointer precision may help, but now your actual mouse when you need precision becomes useless.

Alternative solutions for this is to

- Install free and open source https://www.autohotkey.com/
- create a mouse.ahk file anywhere (contents below)
- copy contents of the gist below
- double click on mouse.ahk - you should see it start working and there should be a AHK icon in your tray
- if you wish scripts to run on startup follow instructions from https://windowsloop.com/run-autohotkey-script-at-windows-startup/
- modify to your liking and share feedback

mouse.ahk contents

```
#SingleInstance Force

varSlowStep := 10
varFastStep := 75
pressingUp := False
pressingDown := False
pressingLeft := False
pressingRight := False
lastHorizontal := 0
lastVertical := 0

;jump to center
NumpadDel::DllCall("SetCursorPos", "int", A_ScreenWidth / 2, "int", A_ScreenHeight / 2)
;right click
#NumpadClear::Click, Right
;ctrl click
^NumpadClear::Send ^{Click}

;scroll
varInScrollMode :=false
ScrollLock::
varInScrollMode := !varInScrollMode
;set state on so it is obvious that now page will be scrolling
if (varInScrollMode)
    SetScrollLockState, On
else
    SetScrollLockState, Off
return

Up::
if (varInScrollMode)
    Click, WU
else
    Send {Up}
return

Down::
if (varInScrollMode)
    Click, WD
else
    Send {Down}
return

Left::
if (varInScrollMode)
    Click, WL
else
    Send {Left}
return

Right::
if (varInScrollMode)
    Click, WR
else
    Send {Right}
return

;hold action
varIsHolding := false
NumpadIns::
varIsHolding := true
Send {Click, Down}
return

;normal click or release hold
NumpadClear::
if (varIsHolding) {
    Send {Click, Up} ;release
    varIsHolding := false
}
else
    Send {Click} ;normal click
return

;modified version of https://github.com/uahnbu/mousekeys/blob/f7640c3ac648761246604685b628defd22be0e19/mouse.ahk#L1
;press down regular
^NumpadUp::
NumpadUp::PressUp()
^NumpadDown::
NumpadDown::PressDown()
^NumpadLeft::
NumpadLeft::PressLeft()
^NumpadRight::
NumpadRight::PressRight()
;release regular
^NumpadUp UP::
NumpadUp UP::ReleaseUp()
^NumpadDown UP::
NumpadDown UP::ReleaseDown()
^NumpadLeft UP::
NumpadLeft UP::ReleaseLeft()
^NumpadRight UP::
NumpadRight UP::ReleaseRight()
;press down diagonal
^NumpadHome::
NumpadHome::PressUp() PressLeft()
^NumpadEnd::
NumpadEnd::PressDown() PressLeft()
^NumpadPgUp::
NumpadPgUp::PressUp() PressRight()
^NumpadPgDn::
NumpadPgDn::PressDown() PressRight()
;release diagonal
^NumpadHome UP::
NumpadHome UP::ReleaseUp() ReleaseLeft()
^NumpadEnd UP::
NumpadEnd UP::ReleaseDown() ReleaseLeft()
^NumpadPgUp UP::
NumpadPgUp UP::ReleaseUp() ReleaseRight()
^NumpadPgDn UP::
NumpadPgDn UP::ReleaseDown() ReleaseRight()
return
;functions to continuously run move functions while keys are pressed
PressUp() {
    global
    if (lastVertical = -1)
        return
    offDirection := ["Left", "", "Right"][lastHorizontal + 2]
    if (pressingDown || lastHorizontal != 0)
        SetTimer % "Move" . ["", "Down"][pressingDown + 1] . offDirection, Delete
    SetTimer % "MoveUp" . offDirection, 1
    lastVertical := -1, pressingUp := True
}

PressDown() {
    global
    if (lastVertical = 1)
        return
    offDirection := ["Left", "", "Right"][lastHorizontal + 2]
    if (pressingUp || lastHorizontal != 0)
        SetTimer % "Move" . ["", "Up"][pressingUp + 1] . offDirection, Delete
    SetTimer % "MoveDown" . offDirection, 1
    lastVertical := 1, pressingDown := True
}

PressLeft() {
    global
    if (lastHorizontal = -1)
        return
    offDirection := ["Up", "", "Down"][lastVertical + 2]
    if (pressingRight || lastVertical != 0)
        SetTimer % "Move" . offDirection . ["", "Right"][pressingRight + 1], Delete
    SetTimer % "Move" . offDirection . "Left", 1
    lastHorizontal := -1, pressingLeft := True
}

PressRight() {
    global
    if (lastHorizontal = 1)
        return
    offDirection := ["Up", "", "Down"][lastVertical + 2]
    if (pressingLeft || lastVertical != 0)
        SetTimer % "Move" . offDirection . ["", "Left"][pressingLeft + 1], Delete
    SetTimer % "Move" . offDirection . "Right", 1
    lastHorizontal := 1, pressingRight := True
}

ReleaseUp() {
    global
    lastVertical := pressingDown, pressingUp := False
    offDirection := ["Left", "", "Right"][lastHorizontal + 2]
    SetTimer % "MoveUp" . offDirection, Delete
    if (pressingDown || lastHorizontal != 0)
        SetTimer % "Move" . ["", "Down"][pressingDown + 1] . offDirection, 1
}

ReleaseDown() {
    global
    lastVertical := -pressingUp, pressingDown := False
    offDirection := ["Left", "", "Right"][lastHorizontal + 2]
    SetTimer % "MoveDown" . offDirection, Delete
    if (pressingUp || lastHorizontal != 0)
        SetTimer % "Move" . ["", "Up"][pressingUp + 1] . offDirection, 1
}

ReleaseLeft() {
    global
    lastHorizontal := pressingRight, pressingLeft := False
    offDirection := ["Up", "", "Down"][lastVertical + 2]
    SetTimer % "Move" . offDirection . "Left", Delete
    if (pressingRight || lastVertical != 0)
        SetTimer % "Move" . offDirection . ["", "Right"][pressingRight + 1], 1
}

ReleaseRight() {
    global
    lastHorizontal := -pressingLeft, pressingRight := False
    offDirection := ["Up", "", "Down"][lastVertical + 2]
    SetTimer % "Move" . offDirection . "Right", Delete
    if (pressingLeft || lastVertical != 0)
        SetTimer % "Move" . offDirection . ["", "Left"][pressingLeft + 1], 1
}

MoveLeft() {
    step := GetStep()
    MouseMove -step, 0, 0, R
}
MoveRight() {
    step := GetStep()
    MouseMove step, 0, 0, R
}
MoveUp() {
    step := GetStep()
    MouseMove 0, -step, 0, R
}
MoveDown() {
    step := GetStep()
    MouseMove 0, step, 0, R
}
MoveUpLeft() {
    step := GetStep()
    MouseMove -step, -step, 0, R
}
MoveUpRight() {
    step := GetStep()
    MouseMove step, -step, 0, R
}
MoveDownLeft() {
    step := GetStep()
    MouseMove -step, step, 0, R
}
MoveDownRight() {
    step := GetStep()
    MouseMove step, step, 0, R
}
GetStep() {
    global
    return GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P") ? varFastStep : varSlowStep
}
```

Mousekeys are activate when NumLock is deactivated.

- **Numpad1-4,6-9:** Move mouse
- **Ctrl + Movement Keys:** Fast move
- **Numpad5:** Left Click (click multiple times for double, triple click)
- **Win + Numpad5:** Right Click
- **Numpad0:** Hold Left MButton, release with **Numpad5**
- **ScrollLock + arrows:** Scroll in any direction

Video walk through is here: https://youtu.be/dYjXPDM2xPQ

Alternative solution is https://github.com/uahnbu/mousekeys